# Solving a second order ODE numerically on Python with SciPy with initial conditions

Tags: python, scipy, ode

Consider the following ODE:

```
y''(x)=2x-2 and y'(0)=0, y(0)=0
```

I've used the following code to try to solve it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dU_dx(U, x):
  return [U[1],2*x-2]

U0=[0,0]
xs = np.linspace(0,3,200)
Us = odeint(dU_dx, U0, xs)
ys = Us[:,0]

plt.plot(xs,ys)
```

I obtain the following graph:

[image]

Which is definitely not the solution since it should be y(x)=x<sup>3</sup>/3-x<sup>2</sup>+2x. What would be the correct code to solve this problem, and what is my code actually doing?

Comment: You have `U0=[0,0]`, so `y(0) = 0` and `y'(0) = 0`.  That implies `y(x) = x**3/3 - x**2`, which is, in fact, what is plotted.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser never mind, I completely missed that. Thanks a lot for the correction. If you don't mind me asking, how would I now solve the problem if I'm now given a condition y(3)=2, y'(6)=1, say?

Comment: @arcbloom Then you need `solve_bvp` with the boundary function `bc(ua,ub): return [ua[0]-2,ub[1]-1]`.